# Get Paypal Payment Details on WooCommerce

Tags: php, paypal, woocommerce

How can I get the payment details from Paypal like PaymentID, PaymentFirstName/LastName, and other details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code PayPal Standard integration uses `valid-paypal-standard-ipn-request` action to process the valid IPN response. You can use the same action to hook into the IPN and get/store any information you want.
To save additional information:

```
// Hook before the code has processed the order
add_action( 'valid-paypal-standard-ipn-request', 'prefix_process_valid_ipn_response', 9 );
function prefix_process_valid_ipn_response( $posted ) {
    if ( ! empty( $posted['custom'] ) && ( $order = prefix_get_paypal_order( $posted['custom'] ) ) ) {

        // Lowercase returned variables.
        $posted['payment_status'] = strtolower( $posted['payment_status'] );

        // Any status can be checked here 
        if ( 'completed' == $posted['payment_status'] ) {
            // Save additional information you want
        }
    }
}

/**
 * From the Abstract "WC_Gateway_Paypal_Response" class
 *
 * @param $raw_custom
 *
 * @return bool|WC_Order|WC_Refund
 */
function prefix_get_paypal_order( $raw_custom ) {
    // We have the data in the correct format, so get the order.
    if ( ( $custom = json_decode( $raw_custom ) ) && is_object( $custom ) ) {
        $order_id  = $custom->order_id;
        $order_key = $custom->order_key;

        // Nothing was found.
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    if ( ! $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ) ) {
        // We have an invalid $order_id, probably because invoice_prefix has changed.
        $order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_key( $order_key );
        $order    = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    }

    if ( ! $order || $order->get_order_key() !== $order_key ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $order;
}
```

You can find the PayPal variables here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#id08CKFJ00JYK

The WC core also saves to the order a lot of the IPN data already. All data is saved to the order meta, so you can access it using `get_post_meta` or `$order->get_meta('meta_key')`.

List by `meta_key`:

`'Payer PayPal address'` - The payer address

`'Payer first name'` - Payer first name

`'Payer last name'` - Payer last name

`'Payment type'` - Payment Type

`'_paypal_status'` - PayPal payment status